# Assigning proper table reference number to a table with nested tabular

Tags: tables

I have a problem with table numbering.
I am now at chapter 9 of the book.
This is the first table of the chapter, so I would expect that it would have caption reference 9.1, but it's giving 9.9

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{TEST}
    \label{Caption}
    
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        & apertura & krok & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} &  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} \\ \hline \hline
        TEXT & number $ number & number & number & number \\ \hline
        TEXT & number $ number & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} & number & number \\ \hline
        TEXT & number $ number & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} & number & number \\ \hline
        TEXT & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} $ number & number & number & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} \\ \hline
        TEXT & number $ number & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} & number & number \\ \hline
        TEXT & number $ number & number & number & number \\ \hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} & number $ number & number & number & number \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

I suppose this is due to the 9 (nine) tabular environment inside the table environment (marked by \begin{tabular} and \end{tabular}), but I have no clue how to fix this.
I checked online some solution, but I was not able to find anything regarding this topic.
Also, \captionof{table}{CAPTION} does not solve the issue.
Also, moving the caption from the top to the bottom is not changing anything:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        & apertura & krok & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} &  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} \\ \hline \hline
        TEXT & number $ number & number & number & number \\ \hline
        TEXT & number $ number & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} & number & number \\ \hline
        TEXT & number $ number & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} & number & number \\ \hline
        TEXT & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} $ number & number & number & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} \\ \hline
        TEXT & number $ number & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} & number & number \\ \hline
        TEXT & number $ number & number & number & number \\ \hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Tabular \end{tabular} & number $ number & number & number & number \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{TEST}
    \label{Caption}
\end{table}
```

Does anyone know if there is a workaround for this?
Any suggestions?
Any different implementation maybe?

Thank you, any suggestion will be really appreciated

Comment: The table number usually does not depend on `tabular` environments but `\caption` and maybe `table` or `longtable` environments, depending on the packages you are using. So it would help a lot, to show not only a code snippet but a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) that can be used to reproduce your issue. The MWE should start with `\documentclass` and end by `\end{document}`.